# Why am I getting this SSL error on an AWS CLI command?

Tags: linux, rhel, aws

I am using the following command to get information on the machines behind my load balancer:

```
aws --region us-east-1 elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-names myLoadBalancer --output text
```

It works flawlessly when I run it from the command line, but as a cron job it gives me the following error:

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)
```

Any ideas? If it were truly a cert issue I would think I would not be able to run the command at all, but I can. It is only an issue when it is a cron job. Additionaly, I set the /etc/python/cert-verification.cfg [https] verify line to be disabled but no luck:

```
[https]
verify=disabled
```

This is how I set up my cron job:

```
sudo su -
crontab -e

#run load balancer script every fifteen minutes
*/15 * * * * /var/scripts/loadbalancerinfo.sh
```

Comment: It appears you are running the cron job as the root user.  When you run on command line, is it running as a different user?  Are there environment variables added on the CLI that are not being loaded for cron?

Comment: I am running both the cron and the command line command as root. I am unsure of how to answer your second question, which tells me I may have a problem there.

Comment: Environment variables would be variables available to the current bash session.  Scripts like `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` can manipulate your environment variables on session initiation, or you can use the `export` bash function to make environment variables in your current session.  You can print all your current environment variables with the `env` command.  My guess is that your interactive bash session (what you get after logging in and starting bash) has some AWS certificate related environment variables that are not in the non-interactive sessions (cron job) for the root user.

Comment: That makes sense but when I tried adding those variable the the cron job itself by adding an export path line, it still did not work.

Comment: Does that mean that you did find differences in your `env` variables?  I do not think you would use `export` for your crontab (I guess that would depend on specifically how you did it though...), but just set the variables directly in the crontab.  If you do want to use `export`, you should be able to add those directly into your /var/scripts/loadbalancerinfo.sh script.